# Is there a maven dependency for kafka 0.10.2.2 version?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using kafka version: 0.10.2.1 and there's a known issue on this version.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5167

It has been fixed in 0.10.2.2 and other higher versions as per the ticket. But I don't see any maven dependency for 0.10.2.2 release.

Comment: 0.10.2 brokers can't support 0.11.x clients https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix

Comment: @cricket_007 That not correct -- you read the wiki page incorrect. It clearly says "any client" for 0.10.2 brokers -- note, that since 0.10.0 clients are backward compatible to older brokers.

Comment: I would recommend to upgrade to 1.0 -- Kafka Streams is backward compatible to older brokers from 0.10.1 on. Note, 1.0.1 was voted recently and vote for 1.1.0 is running as well.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Oops. Autocomplete did that. I did mean *can*

Comment: thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

There is no maven artifact because kafka 0.10.2.2 has not been released.

As Kafka is currently releasing 1.1, it's unclear if 0.10.2.2 will ever be released.

You have 2 options:

- notify the developer's [mailing list](http://kafka.apache.org/contact) with your interest in 0.10.2.2. If enough people are interested it might happen
- start using the [0.10.2 branch](https://github.com/apache/kafka/commits/0.10.2). You'll have to build it yourself but then you'll be running the most up to date 0.10.2 code (including the fix for KAFKA-5167).

Comment: Just upgrade to Kafka Streams to 1.0 :)